# Reading Arabic text from a UTF-8 text file?

Tags: uitextview

Dear All,
I have a strange (stupid) problem when trying to read "Arabic text" from a given file. Let us assume that I have a text file called TEXT.txt which is encoded UTF-8 and looks like this (Arabic text is from RightToLeft):

```
                                                                 :xxx xxxx xx xxx

                                                          .xxx, xxxxxxx xxxxx xxx
```

When I am trying to read TEXT.txt in Xcode by using

```
UITextView *about;
about.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentRight;
NSString *textFilePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"TEXT" ofType:@"txt"];
NSString *fileContents = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:textFilePath encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
about.text = fileContents;
NSLog(@"The text is: \n %@",about.text);
```

Which is I believe is the right way!!! Then it shows on iPhone Simulator and on the device as this:

```
                                                                 xxx xxxx xx xxx:

                                                          xxx, xxxxxxx xxxxx xxx.
```

Which is not the right text to be shown !!!!!!!!!!!!!! What the heck is the problem of the ":" colon and the "." period going on the wrong side. I had a headache of this problem as I have been trying to solve for a long time already. So please Help!!!

Best Regards;

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a way to automatically force right to left layout.  However, you can make a method that will reverse your text.  This will read each character and putting it into a mutable string. A quick search came up with this:

```
-(NSString *) reverseString
{
  NSMutableString *reversedStr;
  int len = [self length];

  // Auto released string
  reversedStr = [NSMutableString stringWithCapacity:len];     

  // Probably woefully inefficient...
  while (len > 0)
    [reversedStr appendString:
         [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%C", [self characterAtIndex:--len]]];   

  return reversedStr;
}
```